# Android - location report stops after display is off

Tags: android, gps, location

**Hello everybody,**
I am trying to create an application that send mobile location (GPS) permanently, so I used Traccar client code, which use service running in background. The application works fine when the display is ON but when it turns OFF the location report stops too.
If you have any idea to make it run even after the display is OFF please help.
**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I get it,
The problem was that Android 6 has a mechanism to optimize battery consumption, I disable it by flowing the next steps:

- Open settings of your device > "Battery"
- In top menu is "Battery optimisation"
- Choose "All apps" in top selector, find Locus Map and select "Don't optimise".

And I disable saving mode of my phone and everything is OK

Comment: Like this every user must do the same !!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you run code inside Activity - Activity is stopped when screen turns off. (see Activity lifecycle). You should use Service for running program in background independenty from UI

Comment: Yes I am using service and the application works fine when the display is on, even after I close it but when the display turns OFF the location report stops, Thanks